# XMADL – Fetching data from local database

Tags: mobile

I am using [XMADL](http://docs.appemble.com/xml_format.html) to write cross-platform mobile app. I have a table ‘user’ in the local database with columns firstname, lastname, email, pwd. How can I display the data when the userprofile screen is invoked? 
The profile screen is defined as

```
    <controls>
        <control name="labelfirstname" type="TEXT" x="2" y="3" width="30" height="8" 
                appearance_name="black" data_type="VARCHAR" 
                default_value="First Name"/>
        <control name="editfirstname" type="EDIT" x="35" y="2" width="50" height="8" 
                appearance_name="edit_box" data_type="VARCHAR" field_name="firstname" 
                default_value="" size="80"/>
        <control name="labellastname" type="TEXT" x="2" y="12" width="30" height="8"
                appearance_name="black" data_type="VARCHAR" 
                default_value="Last Name"/>
        <control name="editlastname" type="EDIT" x="35" y="12" width="50" height="8" 
                appearance_name="edit_box" data_type="VARCHAR" field_name="lastname" 
                default_value="" size="80"/>
        <control name="labelemail" type="TEXT" x="2" y="22" width="30" height="8" 
                appearance_name="black" data_type="VARCHAR" 
                default_value="Email"/>
        <control name="editemail" type="TEXT" x="35" y="22" width="50" height="8" 
                appearance_name="black" data_type="VARCHAR" field_name="email" 
                default_value="" size="80"/>
        <control name="labelpassword" type="TEXT" x="2" y="32" width="30" height="8" 
                appearance_name="black" data_type="VARCHAR" 
                default_value="Password"/>
        <control name="editpassword" type="PASSWORD" x="35" y="32" width="50" height="8" 
                appearance_name="edit_box" word_wrap="0" data_type="VARCHAR" field_name="password" 
                default_value="" size="80"/>
    </controls>
</screen>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the data from the local database and display on the screen by defining the [screen attribute](http://docs.appemble.com/screen.html#screen-attributes) “local_data_source=sql query”.

Replace your  element with the code below.

```
    <screen name="userprofile" screen_type="SCREEN" allow_reorientation="true" allowed_layouts="BOTH" scroll="VERTICAL"
        width="100" height="100" local_data_source="select lastname, firstname, email, password from user_details where email=&apos;&lt;email&gt;&apos;">
```

The query results will be column_name / value pairs. The value will be assigned to the control if the column_name of the data table matches the field_name of the control.

Once the screen is invoked, the data will be fetched from the database and made available to the controls with field_name firstname, lastname, email and pwd for display.